# Какие есть библиотеки для входа и отправки сообщений на сайте (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек

Какие есть библиотеки на Python, которые позволяют войти на сайт и отправлять сообщения через пользователя, с помощью которого был произведён вход (Хочется автоматизировать задачу отправки утром галочки о присутствии)?. Может ли ещё с этим справиться библиотека Requests?

Comment: Почему не использовать postman?
Пишешь запрос передаешь аргумент и просто файлик через планировщик ежедневно запускаешь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

библиотека requests позволяет только полностью получить статическую страницу(если конечно у сервиса нет открытого api с помощью которого можно вести взаимодействие с сайтом)

Могу посоветовать библиотеку selenium, с ее помощью можно обеспечить полное взаимодействие с сайтом

[Пост на хабре о selenium](https://habr.com/ru/post/248559/)

Comment: Уточню для себя: селениум разве может посылать rest запросы?

Comment: @Battrip а причем тут rest , автору вопроса нужно зайти на сайт и поставить галочку какую то, и чтобы все это было автоматизировано,selenium позволяет взаимодействовать с сайтом,

Comment: rest запросы позволят быстрей выполнить задачу. Видимо мы по разному поняли задачу...

Answer (score 2):

Ну... :

- C помощью [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) можно кое-что заполнить, но не всегда.
- У многих сайтов есть API (e.g. y этого сайта [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/)) — и тогда пользуйтесь им и только им.
- Ну а если нет API — то [Selenium](https://habr.com/ru/post/248559/).